# Win7: PC with static IP address still requesting DHCP address

Tags: windows-7, networking, dhcp

I've some PCs in my LAN, mostly Win7, to which I've configured a static IP address.

Neverthless, on my DHCP server (pfSense) I see those computers with a freshly created DHCP lease! And even if I remove the lease manually, after some time I see them appearing back again.

How is this possible? How can I stop the interface from requesting an IP address?

All the configuration is manual (IP, DNS...). IPv6 is disabled.

Comment: did you try disabling the DHCP client service completely  and stopping it, in windows services?  That would be the common practice I would use , when locking to a specific single static address.

Comment: I tried disabling DHCP client service (which was active, indeed), rebooted but it's still requesting DHCP

Comment: Did you try blocking port 68 inbound connection in Windows firewall?

Comment: I can, but it looks weird to me having to block it at firewall level, while it should NOT run!